# YouTube Data API (Java) CommentSnippet.getAuthorGoogleplusProfileUrl() returns null

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am extracting a huge chunk of YouTube comments for a particular research purpose. Along with a comment, I am being able to extract the author display name but when I try to extract the google plus profile URL of the author it is returning null for all the authors of more than 10,000 comments! What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to link a youtube commenter to a google+ profile?

```
if(!snippet.isEmpty())
{
    pw.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());//works fine
    pw.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay()); //works fine
    //the following line always returns null!
    pw.println("  - Google+ Profile URL: " + snippet.getAuthorGoogleplusProfileUrl()); //always returns null
    pw.println("  - Author Channel ID: " + snippet.getAuthorChannelId()); //works fine
    pw.println("  - Author Channel URL: " + snippet.getAuthorChannelUrl());//works fine
    pw.println("\n-------------------------------------------------\n");
}
//pw: a PrintWriter object
//snippet: a CommentSnippet object
```

Please help! I am absolutely stuck at this...
Regards.

Comment: Try to check at least one user with getAuthorGoogleplusProfileUrl? To check if you have implemented it incorrectly. Checking the [document](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/CommentSnippet.html#getAuthorGoogleplusProfileUrl()) `getAuthorGoogleplusProfileUrl`returns a value or null for none. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot for your reply. I have checked again and again but could not figure out what the problem is. I have gone through the documentation as well. Can you please suggest any other way of connecting a YouTube commenter with a Google+ profile? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the method is deprecated since June 13, 2016.

Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823274/how-to-get-a-users-google-id-from-a-youtube-channel-id).